# SQL: Grouping results by the date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
EventTime         | InTeam    | Points |
----------------------------------------
2014-07-16 11:40      True       10
2014-07-16 10:00     False       20
2014-07-16 09:20      True       30
2014-07-15 11:20     False        5
2014-07-15 10:20      True       10
2014-07-15 09:00     False       10
```

Is it possible to make a query that results with:

```
EventDate   | InTeam Points | Not In Team Point |
-------------------------------------------------
2014-07-16                40                  20
2014-07-15                10                  15
```

Where `InTeam Points` is a sum of all team points during the day and `Not In Team Point` is a sum of not in team points during the day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select date(eventtime) as eventtime,
       sum(case when inteam = 'true' then points end) as in_team_points,
       sum(case when inteam = 'false' then points end) as not_in_team_points
from your_table
group by date(eventtime)
```